# In EXCEL, turning off automatc calculations on cells or on a wroksheet, not on a workbook

Tags: excel

In Excel 2010, is there any way to turn off the automatic calculation on  specific cell(s) or sheet? I found that the Excel option for that applies to the whole workbook.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Worksheet.EnableCalculation=False to turn off calculation for a worksheet. But be aware that restting it to True will make the next calculation of that worksheet a full calculation rather than a recalculation.

For specific cells there is no good solution: you have to archive the formula somewhere, convert to values and the re-apply the formula when you want to recalculate it.